# Removing '|' from object names?

Tags: r

I have created a data frame in R with the following name:

```
table_file1_C.txt|file2_C.txt
```

This name is was generated by the assign() function, in reference to a single .txt file that was generated by a program run on command line. Here is a sample from the loop that created this object:

```
assign(x=paste("table_",
               dir(file.dir, pattern="\\.txt$")[i],
               sep=''),
       value=tmpTables[[i]])#tmpTables holds the data I'm manipulating, as read in from readHTMLtable
```

The issue is that I an unable to reference this object after its creation;

```
>table_file1_C.txt|file2_C.txt
Error: object 'file2_C.txt' not found
```

I believe that R is seeing the '|' character, and reading it as an instruction, not a part of the object's name, even though it already accepted it as part of the object's name.

So, I need to strip the | from the object's name. I planned to accomplish this with gsub() embedded within the assign() function, using something like this:

```
assign(x=paste("table_",#creating the name of the object
               gsub(x=dir(file.dir, pattern="\\.txt$")[i],
                        pattern="|",
                        replacement="."),#need to remove the | characters!!
               sep=''),
       value=tmpTables[[i]])
```

However, this output gives something like this:

```
[1] ".t.a.b.l.e._.f.i.l.e.1...t.x.t.|.f.i.l.e.2...t.x.t."
```

As you can see, the name has been mangled, and the | has not actually been removed.

I need to find a way to remove the | from the name, so I can process the object that I have created. Or, prevent it from being included in the name in the first place. I can only do this within R, as I cannot modify the output of the program that I used to generate the data.

Does this make sense? Let me know if more information is needed. Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Comment: This is a good reason you should not be using `get()` or `assign()`. Often there is no need to create a bunch of separate objects in the global environment. If they are related, keep them in a list. Why not keep them in the `tmpTables` list? But if you want further help, you need to make your sample reproducible. We can't run the same code and get the same results. But if you do `assign("a|b", 4)`, you can get the value with `\`a|b\``

Comment: Thanks, I am working on an implementation that doesn't require creating new objects.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the `|` character in the regular expression.  Otherwise it is an empty pattern, which matches everything.

Escaping the character with brackets (character class):

```
x <- 'a|b'
gsub('[|]', '.', x)
## [1] "a.b"
```

Escaping with a backslash:

```
gsub('\\|', '.', x)
## [1] "a.b"
```

If you don't escape the `|` character, it is an "or" operation in the regular expression.  Nothing or nothing, same as matching nothing.  Thus it inserts the `.` between each character:

```
gsub('', '.', x)
## [1] ".a.|.b."

gsub('|', '.', x)  # Same as above
## [1] ".a.|.b."
```

Comment: Yeah I thought about escaping the character but ' ' was not working, it was only returning the object name. I ended up getting it to work by using ` to escape the | character.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, escaping with ' ' as per Matthew Lundberg did not work correctly for me, but escaping with ` did.

```
> 'file1.txt|file2.txt'
[1] "file1.txt|file2.txt"

>`denovo_AR_C.txt|FOXA1_C.txt`
*data*
```

Thanks go to Matthew